# Problem with equation

Tags: analysis

I have problem with showing that Left side is equal to right side.

$$
\frac {1-e^{2i\pi yKr/2^n}} {1-e^{2i\pi yr /2^n}} = e^{i\pi (K-1)r/2^n}\frac{\sin(\pi yKr/2^n)}{\sin(\pi y r / 2^n)}
$$

My only idea is to use this but i didn't get any good result from this.
$$
e^{inx}= \cos(nx) + i\sin(nx)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first off we need the identity $$\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}=\sin{x}$$

Then we just factor out one half of each exponential from numerator and denominator.

$$\frac {1-e^{2i\pi yKr/2^n}} {1-e^{2i\pi yr /2^n}} = \frac{e^{i\pi yKr/2^n}}{e^{i\pi yr /2^n}}\cdot\frac {(-1)(e^{i\pi yKr/2^n}-e^{-i\pi yKr/2^n})} {(-1)(e^{i\pi yr /2^n}-e^{-i\pi yr /2^n})} = e^{i\pi (K-1)r/2^n}\frac {(e^{i\pi yKr/2^n}-e^{-i\pi yKr/2^n})} {(e^{i\pi yr /2^n}-e^{-i\pi yr /2^n})} = e^{i\pi (K-1)r/2^n}\frac{\sin(\pi yKr/2^n)}{\sin(\pi y r / 2^n)}$$

Comment: thx, nice solution